# QTP find object in a Browser frame in a Java frame in an IE window?

Tags: java, qtp, sap-basis, netweaver

So we have a bit of an unusual setup in our software.  On a webpage, we have a Java applet.  QTP can handle objects on the webpage itself or the Java applet itself quite easily.  The problem comes when the Java applet then includes an internal Browser frame that pulls data from an SAP application.

When using SAP add-in and trying to capture the objects in the object repository, nothing is getting added into the repository. So there is no way we can identify the objects.

When using both SAP and Java add-in, we can identify the frame but not the objects embedded into the frame.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: When you spy on a `SapEdit` for example does it show up as a `WebEdit` or as a `WinObject`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the web editor, QTP has a special plugin (for which of course you have to pay more) just for that corner case.